# Firebase - Vue database integration not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs3

I am trying integrating Firebase with Vue 4 application is currently getting the following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: *db__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.default.database is not a function

I am using
"firebase": "^9.0.0"
"vue": "^3.0.0"

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";


const firebaseConfig = {
// keys
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getDatabase(app);

export {db}
```

My function call is as below

```js
import {reactive} from 'vue';
import { ref, set, push } from "firebase/database";
import {db} from "./db"


export default {
  setup(){
    const inputUsername = ref("");
    const inputMessage = ref("");
    const state = reactive({
        username: "",
        messages:[]
    });

    const Login = () =>{
      if(inputUsername.value != "" || inputUsername.value != null){
       state.username = inputUsername.value;
       inputUsername.value = "";
      }
    }
    const SendMessage = () => {
    //   const messagesRef = db.database().ref("messages");
      if (inputMessage.value === "" || inputMessage.value === null) {
        return;
      }
      const message = {
        username: state.username,
        content: inputMessage.value
      }
      set(push(ref(db, 'messages')), message);

    //   messagesRef.push(message);
      inputMessage.value = "";
    }
    return{
    inputUsername,
    Login,
    state,
    inputMessage,
    SendMessage
    }
  }
}
```

I tried the following [the following suggestion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade)  but it didn't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new modular SDK does not use namespaces anymore. So you cannot use `app.database()`. You can simply export a database instance from the file where you initialize Firebase as shown below:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getDatabase(app);

export {db}
```

Then import this wherever you need and use it:

```js
import { ref, child, get } from "firebase/database";
import {db} from "../path/to/firebase.js"

const message = {
  username: state.username,
  content: inputMessage.value
}

set(push(ref(db, 'messages')), message);
```

You can learn more about the new syntax in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data)

---

> Uncaught TypeError: db._checkNotDeleted is not a function

This error arise due to the fact the you are importing `ref` from both `firebase` and `vue`. Please import Firebase's `ref` as `fireRef`.

```js
import { reactive, ref } from "vue";
import { ref as fireRef, set, push } from "firebase/database";
import { db } from "./db";

// usage 
set(push(fireRef(db, "messages")), message);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am getting an error in this implementation.   Uncaught TypeError: db._checkNotDeleted is not a function

Comment: @V5NXT that sounds like a different issue to me. Your code has no checkNotDeleted function

Comment: Are you sure? its a function of the 'db' object.

Comment: @V5NXT can you share relevant parts of code where that's being used?

Comment: I have updated the question with the entire component and your changes.

Comment: @V5NXT I can't reproduce that issue. Have you tried reinstalling the firebase module and restarting the Vue dev server? If the error still persists can you share a complete screenshot of the error instead of the first line only ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236603/discussion-between-v5nxt-and-dharmaraj).

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue: `db._checkNotDeleted is not a function` on firebase v9.1.3 and vue2. I have moved firebase db initialization into a different file and I import ref as fireRef.. yet no luck:(

Comment: @lead-free if that's the case then I'd recommend posting a new question with your code and relevant details